I did not get Fide rating although I met all the requirements why?
I scored 0.5 in a FIDE tournament against 5 rated players and my performance rating was 1284. Why did I not get FIDE rating? Do I need to play another tournament in order to get a rating?

See https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/42604/what-are-fide-really-hoping-to-achieve-by-the-proposed-rating-changes-from-janua

Since last rating change you need to get at least 1400 to get rated.
